# Dynamic Search with TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a search page that I am creating to query my database that looks like below.

I am trying to determine the best way to determine the best way to create my stored procedure for this. I want to display results that match any of the data submitted and ignore the fields of empty data.

What is an ideal way to approach this?

[image]

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is in your `WHERE` criteria, use `OR @param IS NULL`.  Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedure @param int AS
SELECT Field
FROM YourTable
WHERE (SomeField = @param OR @param IS NULL)
```

Comment: When I have multiple fields, do I use OR  or  AND with the multiple WHERE variables?

Comment: Depends on your desired results.  Use `AND` in your `WHERE` criteria if you want all criteria to be matched.  Use `OR` in your `WHERE` criteria if you want any of your criteria to be matched.  You probably want to use `AND`.

Comment: Dynamic SQl is often better than this espcially if the search conditions mean you may or may not need to join to a particular table.

Comment: There `WHERE` condition can be made so that a `NULL` parameter became a tautology (like 1=1) using `WHERE SomeField = COALESCE(@param, SomeField)`, and tautology are not evaluted

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be to use Dynamic sql and filter results based on what parameter you pass to the procedure.  something like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SearchProc
@Col1_Val [Datatype],
@Col2_Val [Datatype],
@Col3_Val [Datatype]
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Sql = N' SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1 = 1'
            + CASE WHEN @Col1_Val IS NOT NULL 
                   THEN N' AND Col1 = @Col1_Val ' ELSE '' END
            + CASE WHEN @Col2_Val IS NOT NULL 
                   THEN N' AND Col2 = @Col2_Val ' ELSE '' END                  
            + CASE WHEN @Col3_Val IS NOT NULL 
                   THEN N' AND Col3 = @Col3_Val ' ELSE '' END            

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                       ,N'@Col1_Val [Datatype],@Col2_Val [Datatype],@Col3_Val [Datatype]'
                       ,@Col1_Val [Datatype],@Col2_Val [Datatype],@Col3_Val [Datatype]

END
```